# Lisp - is there anyway to convert "(" to symbol '(

Tags: lisp

Is there anyway to convert string parentheses "(" to symbol parentheses '( in lisp?
For example while converting list of strings to list of symbols;
("(" ")") => (( ))

Comment: Which lisp? Common Lisp?

Comment: Having symbols `(` and `)` is usually not a good idea. You might want to explain what you really want to do.

Comment: @David Young It is common lisp. Recently I started working on it, I am trying to convert list of strings to list of symbols. I failed to convert special characters like left parentheses or right parentheses.

Answer (score 7):

The "(" character can be entered as `#\(`

If you want a symbol whose print name is "(" you can enter it using the vertical bars:

```
'|(|
```

Or if you have a list of strings, where each string is something like "(", you can use intern to convert each string to a symbol:

```
(intern "(") => |(|
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use escape, like this:

```
* (list '\( '\) 123)
(|(| |)| 123)
```

According to the one of the Common Lisp reader algorithm's rules (taken from CLTL2):

```
5. If x is a single escape character (normally \), then read the next 
character and call it y (but if at end of file, signal an error 
instead). Ignore the usual syntax of y and pretend it is a 
constituent whose only attribute is alphabetic.
```